# Selecting items from MySQL for a status update feed efficiently while accounting for possible spam

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, sorting, memcached

I am creating a "status update" feed where users can post general messages that can be viewed by other users (think status updates in facebook, twitter tweets, etc.). First of all, each post is assigned a rank score at the time a post is created and saved to the database. This rank score combined with a time decay function are what is used to assign a "true rank" to each post at the time the feed is generated and presented to the user. This true rank is how items are ultimately sorted.

A complexity arose when introducing a strategy to combat "spam" (we don't want users to be able to post very rapidly and hog the top spot in the feed). The strategy is to track how many times the user has posted in, say, the last hour. For every subsequent post added within the last hour, the assigned rank score is penalized. The more posts by a user within the last hour, the greater the rank score penalty. The idea here is to push potential spam further down the feed, while still giving it a chance to display.

Following illustrates how the feed would be sorted after four items are quickly posted by the same user if we're not accounting for spam.

```
Item 1: Posted 1 min ago. True Rank = 0.99. user_id = 666.
Item 2: Posted 2 min ago. True Rank = 0.98. user_id = 666. SPAM.
Item 3: Posted 3 min ago. True Rank = 0.97. user_id = 666. SPAM.
Item 4: Posted 4 min ago. True Rank = 0.96. user_id = 666. SPAM.
Item 5: Posted 5 min ago. True Rank = 0.95. user_id = 100.
Item 6: Posted 6 min ago. True Rank = 0.94. user_id = 100.
```

Following is what is desired. Notice that posts by user_id = 666 fall down the feed after the first post.

```
Item 1: Posted 1 min ago. True Rank = 0.99. user_id = 666.
Item 5: Posted 5 min ago. True Rank = 0.95. user_id = 100.
Item 6: Posted 6 min ago. True Rank = 0.94. user_id = 100.
Item 2: Posted 2 min ago. True Rank = 0.88. user_id = 666. SPAM.
Item 3: Posted 3 min ago. True Rank = 0.77. user_id = 666. SPAM.
Item 4: Posted 4 min ago. True Rank = 0.66. user_id = 666. SPAM.
```

### Problem

I have a strategy for doing this. As mentioned above, I'm tracking the number of posts per hour for each user and deducting from the rank score if necessary. This is no problem.

The problem arises when thinking about how to efficiently select items from the database each time we're preparing the feed for a user. This is about performance. I want to select, say, 1000 feed items at a time (1000 initially, and 1000 each subsequent fetch if the user requests more). But what if those first 1000 items are all or mostly spam? Selecting all items and then preparing the feed would technically work, but the number of items in the system is potentially very large.

I'm struggling to create an algorithm that selects items for the feed without the need to pull out large amounts at a time, and yet gives every feed item a chance to display on the feed, even if its rank is extremely low.

Artificial solutions like letting the user only post n items per hour is not an option.

For what it's worth, the tools at my disposal for this are MySQL, Memcached, and PHP.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: wouldn't it be a better idea to just not post the spam in the first place? letting the spam see the light of day just encourages more spam.

Comment: Apologies if how spam is defined here can seem misleading. It should more accurately be called "potential spam". We want to still display all items because posting frequently is not necessarily a bad thing (we will have a reporting function for users to alert us of truly malicious posts). In any case, we want to grant all posts a chance to sink or swim (perhaps unless an item's rank is EXTREMELY LOW).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way of making the reads really efficient is to work out when to exclude posts at INSERT time (perhaps have a separate notifications table and use some rate limiting, e.g. leaky bucket algorithm, to work out which ones to exclude).

To do something close to what you want to do with the data you have at the moment you could do something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c20ac/8

It's saying something like "only allow one post to show from each user in every N posts". You'd have to tune the N value (5 in the example) for the rate of data you have but it works reasonably well with the data.

Feature-wise a nicer version could be (if you store the timestamp of the post) to do the division based on the time of the post, well the difference between the time now and the time of the post. I think this would work out slower though as you'd be grouping on a derived column.

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I am working on a solution right now with one of these principles in mind. Namely, doing more logic up front at INSERT time. I'll come back here with an update once more detail has been worked out.